# GitHubのリポジトリ内にあるarticlesフォルダ内ファイル数を絞って取得したい。

Tags: github, webapi

これでリポジトリ内のフォルダ内ファイルを全件取得出来ます。
`https://api.github.com/repos/user/zenn-content/contents/articles`

リポジトリページ：
https://github.com/wimpykid719/zenn-content/tree/master/articles

ブログにページネーションの機能を追加したいので、一気に全件ではなくファイル数を5件等で取得したいのです。GitHubのAPIでは可能でしょうか？

ドキュメントを見たのですが、レポジトリ数の取得を調整するのは `page=5&per_page=10`等のパラメータを設定する事で出来るみたいなんですが、リポジトリ内のファイルに対して行う記述は見つけられませんでした。

ご存知の方がいらしたら教えて頂けないでしょうか？よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

GitHubを見たのですが、Zenn(https://zenn.dev/)のZenn CLIをつかっている見たいですね。
Zennで記事を書くなら、Zenn CLIのチュートリアルを見た方が良いでしょう。そうでなければ、GitHub上の記事をどのようにデプロイしBlogにするかの具体的なイメージを書いた方がいいと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。記事自体はマークダウンファイルに記述しているだけで、Zennも作成しているブログもGitHubのリポジトリにアップされているマークダウンファイルを取得して記事を生成していると言ったイメージだと思っています。なのでGitHubのAPIで取得するファイル数を絞れればと思いました。